# Upload file using S3 presigned-url to device farm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url, aws-device-farm

Trying to upload a .apk to my device farm project without success. I have created this code to perform the task:

```
CLIENT = boto3.client("devicefarm", region_name="us-west-2")

def create_upload(project_arn, file_name, type):
    response = CLIENT.create_upload(
        projectArn=project_arn,
        name=file_name,
        type=type,
        contentType="application/octet-stream"
    )
    print(response)

    try:
        payload = {
            "file": open("app-release-04.apk", "rb")
        }
        header = {
            "contentType": "application/octet-stream"
        }
        app_arn = response["upload"]["arn"]
        signed_url = response["upload"]["url"]

        time.sleep(10)
        status = CLIENT.get_upload(arn=app_arn)
        print(status)

        api_response = requests.put(url=signed_url, files=payload, headers=header)
        print(api_response)
    except KeyError:
        raise KeyError(f"Upload failed! With project_arn: {project_arn},"
                    f"file_name: {file_name} and type: {type}: {response}")

    return app_arn
```

It works but and the `api_response` return `<Response [200]>`. However, I can't see the file anywhere in device farm. What am I doing wrong in my python code?

If I use the cli + curl then it works:

```
aws devicefarm create-upload --project-arn <PROJECT_ARN> --name app-release-04.apk --type ANDROID_APP --region us-west-2

curl -T app-release-04.apk <SIGNED_URL>
```

Comment: Can you move the code:
`time.sleep(10); status = CLIENT.get_upload(arn=app_arn)`
To the lines after your requests.put command, and print the status output? Usually, you wouldn't see the file if the status is "FAILED", but would see the file if the status is "SUCCEEDED".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was first the wrong header format `"contentType"` instead of `"content-type"`. Then I changed the payload to look like this:

```
data = open(f"{file_path}/{file_name}", 'rb')
requests.put(url=signed_url, data=data, headers=header)
```

Hence, use `data` instead of `files` in the put request.